# c# mongodb possible deadlock in FindAsync extention

Tags: c#, multithreading, mongodb, mongodb-query, deadlock

Im trying to cut out the code im writing.
There is this piece of code where in every `FindAsync` we need to write:

```
using (var cursor = await SomeCollection.FindAsync(filter, options))
{
     while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
     {
          var batch = cursor.Current;
          foreach (var item in batch)
          {
              //do something
          }
     }
}
```

I came up with an extention. My code:

```
public static async Task<List<T>> GetResultsFromFindAsync<T>(this Task<IAsyncCursor<T>> find)
{
    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    using (var cursor = await find)
    {
        while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
        {
            var batch = cursor.Current;
            foreach (var item in batch)
            {
                result.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

and now, I only use:

```
List<MyObject> lst = await SomeCollection.FindAsync(filter, options).GetResultsFromFindAsync();
```

Question is: Can it cause deadlocks since there are 2 async tasks involved in a process with a single `Await` caluse.
I know that the process really contains 2 `Await`caluses, but, wont they just conflict which each other, or might cause to a data loss?

I executed a FindAsync using this extention and got my data, so its working, but the test doesn't gurentee deadlocks 100% of the times if it can occur.

I would very much like to know why or why not.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can this cause deadlocks? Yes, but not for the reasons you listed.

If someone decides to call your method synchronously and uses `Wait` or `Result` on the returned `Task`, they *may* get a deadlock. SO is littered with "why does my task never complete" questions for that exact reason. Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on all `Task`s awaited inside your `GetResultsFromFindAsync` to safeguard yourself.

With that said, if `GetResultsFromFindAsync` is always consumed asynchronously, there is no issue.

With regards to there only being a "single `await` clause" - that's not actually true. You are `await`ing the `Task` returned by `FindAsync` inside your `GetResultsFromFindAsync` implementation, thus propagating its completion and exceptions (if any). When you call

`SomeCollection.FindAsync(filter, options).GetResultsFromFindAsync()`

, you are in effect awaiting both `Tasks` (as the inner `Task` is awaited by the outer `Task`). If `FindAsync` happens to throw (asynchronously), the `Task` returned by `GetResultsFromFindAsync` will automatically transition to `Faulted` state and the exception will be re-thrown when the outer `Task` is awaited.

In conclusion, there is nothing technically wrong with the method you have written, although introducing `ConfigureAwait(false)` wouldn't hurt.

**EDIT**

Having said all of the above, I would personally consider merging the two calls into one, so that calling `FindAsync` is the responsibility of `GetResultsFromFindAsync`. This is to prevent consumers from reusing the cursor returned by `FindAsync` as I expect the following will fail:

```
IAsyncCursor<T> cursor = await SomeCollection.FindAsync(filter, options);
List<MyObject> lst1 = await cursor.GetResultsFromFindAsync();
List<MyObject> lst2 = await cursor.GetResultsFromFindAsync(); // BOOM.
```

Comment: obviously all my prior calls using await and not .Result or .Wait. I know about the deadlock effect they can occur. so, ill sum it up as: "Non-deadlock" code. Agree?

Comment: @OriRefael, yep, that sums it up. There is also no "data loss" issue here as the outer task cannot proceed with the bulk of its work before the inner task is completed.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET driver already offers extension methods for this type of thing. ToList, ToListAsync, and ForEachAsync are all available.

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/crud/reading/#iteration